# Cant get my InstanceID with GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM in my app for the first time, so I've followed the steps and there's an error that make my app doesn't get the token for registration in my sv.

It says:

```
09-30 23:05:52.196 31461-31514/com.comgonzalovillarbaribus E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
09-30 23:05:52.200 31461-31514/com.comgonzalovillarbaribus E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

I don't know what the problem is, my manifest is correct, my `GCM_SENDER_ID` is ok.

Here is where I ask for my token:

```
    // Set GCM
    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    ...


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    HomeActivity.newRegID=token;
    //WebServerRegistrationTask webServer=new WebServerRegistrationTask();
    //webServer.execute();

    // Create params
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("regID",token);

    // Doing the req
    AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    asyncHttpClient.post(Constants.WEB_SERVER_URL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String key = responseBody.toString();
            Log.e("key", key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.e("error", "conexion");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my updated manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityHorariosLinea"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_horarios_linea">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityHorariosParada"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_horarios_parada" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityListaTrabajos"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_lista_trabajos" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCM.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I already have the api enabled in the console.  My app is not in the play store.

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Try some of the following `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />` (to be continued)

Comment: `<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: `<service android:name=".GcmService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>` you should change `android:name` depending on your package structure

Comment: You should read the [most updated document here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I got same error, after recheck, i forgot to do 2 steps below:

> Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:
>
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
>
> Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

In your project `AndroidManifest.xml` you have given following permission for package `com.example.gcm` which does not exist

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Your application package is `com.comgonzalovillarbaribus` so try this line:

```
<permission android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Remove this `com.example.gcm` package name from your `AndroidManifest.xml`

**EDIT:**

Use this also instead you have mentioned in comment.

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.comgonzalovillarbaribus"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```